# Interpreting Diode-Module Datasheet (Voltage Drop)

Tags: diodes, datasheet, semiconductors

I'm trying to interpret the datasheet of a Dual-Diode Module, specifically the MF200C12F2N. The internal Circuit Structure is given below:

[image]

The Forward Voltage is given as 2.3V without any further explanations. Would this be the voltage drop across a single diode (i.e., across Terminals 1-2) or across the entire Structure (i.e. 1-3)?

Comment: 2.3v @200 A ... for a single diode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at a [MF200C12F2N](https://www.tme.com/Document/dd4448e1ac18964d171280c598034132/MF200C12F2N.pdf) datasheet:

1. I<sub>F(AV)</sub> and I<sub>F(RMS)</sub> are specified as `Per Diode`
2. As the question notes V<sub>F</sub> is not explicitly described as if for a single diode or across the entire structure.
3. However, the conditions for the V<sub>F</sub> does state for a particular value of I<sub>F</sub>

My interpretation is that the *Forward Voltage of 2.3 V* (typical value at T<sub>J</sub>=25°C ?) is thus for a single diode.

Given this is a diode assembly for high current the power dissipation is an important consideration. The performance curves also show the forward voltage decreases as the junction temperature increases. I.e. there is also a temperature dependency on the forward voltage for a single diode:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would be shocked if it weren't per-diode.

But they don't explicitly say so, so, if you need design assurance: ask the manufacturer to clarify, or shop around for a better-specified part.